# Get nested JSON object from a JSON Array

Tags: arrays, json, getjson

May i know how to get JSON object from an json array??

JSON:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "user": {
            "id": 20710,
            "username": "abc",
            "first_name": "",
            "last_name": "",
        },
        "action": {
            "name": "xxx",
            "date": 19/01/01,
        },
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "user": {
            "username": "xyx",
            "first_name": "xxx",
            "last_name": "yyy",
        },
        "action": {
            "name": "xxx",
            "date": 19/05/01,
        },

    },]
```

I want to get username of these users in a list, but i cant get the value when i get this json from api as JSONArray.

My code:

```
public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d("Create Response", response.toString());

                    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response;
                    try {
                    if (jsonArray != null) {
                        int len = jsonArray.length();
                        for (int i=0;i<len;i++){
                            JSONObject c=response.getJSONObject(1);
                            String id = c.getString(i);

                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            map.put("id", id);
                                feeds_List.add(map);
                        }
                    }
```

I cannot use

```
JSONObject object=JsonArray.getJSONObject("user");
```

here,

it only accept int for `getJSONObject("user");` if it is `JSONArray`

Comment: Have you managed to parse the JSON into an JSON array? If yes, what is your next problem, if no, why not?

Comment: @Smutje i can get the json into json array, but then i don't know how to get the json object "inside" it , 1)i can get values like id , but cannot get object like "user" and "action" since it is nested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use like this also.Suppose response String is *userInfo*

```
ArrayList<String> usernames = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray userList = new JSONArray(userInfo);
for (int j = 0; j < userList.length(); j++) {
  JSONObject userObject = new JSONObject(userList.getString(j));
  String user = userObject.getString("user");
  JSONObject usernameInfo = new JSONObject(user);
  usernames.add(usernameInfo.getString("username"));

}
```

Try this, if not working please mention me in comment.